# Should I build a shield to protect building wire installed inside cabinet?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I had a new custom made cabinet installed and it forced me to move an electrical box from the wall to the inside of a cabinet. Work was done by an electrician. The outlet is now on the outside of cabinet and here is the work inside the cabinet:

Is this a correct and safe way to do this ? Any suggestions to improve safety?

I was thinking of adding a little wood boxing to contain the outlet box and wire to increase safety.

Thanks for your help, I'm very new at this!

[image]

Comment: What scenario can you imagine wherein that cable would be damaged? With the metal box in place, you'd have to try pretty hard. There are probably wires in your basement or garage in far greater jeopardy. Forget about it.

Comment: As others have said, this isn't likely to be unsafe (though I think my electrician would have used armored cable), but for aesthetics, you might consider a 3 sided box that just sits over everything.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the input, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine and quite safe. The metal box could even be sitting out in the open and would be just fine. I have a similar setup in one of my kitchen cabinets. The only concerns I know of are:

- Drawers - This does not appear to be the case here at all, but if you have a drawer that can bump into a cable when it is opening/closing then that would be a problem.
- Loose Cable - Also not a problem here. Even when it is a problem, it is usually not a problem to fix. Cables basically need to be short (as is the case here - just a couple of inches extra which is good in case anything ever needs to be changed) or secure and out-of-the-way (and this is clearly out of the way).

Comment: In Ontario Canada at least, a cable staple is required within the first six inches of a box. In this case, I'd probably put one about 1-2" above the hole.